# Git Push to Heroku, receiving "Invalid RUBY_VERSION specified:"

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, rubygems

I'm trying to push an app to heroku using "git push heroku master".

In my Gemfile, I have the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby 'ruby 1.9.3' 
gem 'foreman'
```

but when I try to push to heroku, I get the following error:

```
!     Invalid RUBY_VERSION specified: Gemfile-syntax-error:-<!DOCTYPE-html>-^-/tmp/build_o93twnijmxig/Gemfile:5:-syntax-error,-unexpected-'<'-<html>-^-/tmp/build_o93twnijmxig/Gemfile:7:-syntax-error,-unexpected-'<'-<meta-charset='utf-8'>-^-/tmp/build_o93twnijmxig/Gemfile:8:-syntax-error,-unexpected-'<'-<meta-http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"-content="IE=edge">-^-/tmp/build_o93twnijmxig/Gemfile:8:-syntax-error,-unexpected-tIDENTIFIER,-expecting-$end-<meta-http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"-content="IE=edge">-^

!     Valid versions: ruby-1.9.3-p0, ruby-1.9.3-p125, rbx-1.2.4, rbx-2.0.0dev-20120115-1.9, rbx-2.0.0dev-20120115-1.8, rbx-2.0.0dev-20120123-1.9, rbx-2.0.0dev-20120123-1.8, ruby-1.9.2-p290, jruby-1.6.5.1, jruby-1.6.7, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-1.8.7, ruby-1.9.3-jruby-1.7.0.preview1, ruby-1.8.7-jruby-1.7.0.preview1, ruby-1.9.3-rbx-2.0.0dev, ruby-1.8.7-rbx-2.0.0dev
!
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

When I enter: heroku config -s | grep PATH 
I get the following output:

```
PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

and running: heroku run "ruby -v" ,outputs:

```
Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.1
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

But when I try to run bundle install in the app directory, I get this strange message:

```
 Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified ruby 1.9.3
```

Comment: Just an FYI if someone has the same problem: it seems that a badly formatted gemfile can also result in this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3' 
gem 'foreman'
```

Comment: Thanks halfelf, I changed the Gemfile, you're right. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error, saying that "Invalid RUBY_VERSION specified". Btw, ruby --version returns: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: You're not going to need forman in your production environment. Move it to the development group.